# bme680_i2c: Unknown symbol __devm_regmap_init_i2c (err -2)

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to build bme680 driver for raspberry pi 3. In compiling process, every is well without any error. But when I `insmod` the driver, I received an error:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module bme680_i2c.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

Check `dmesg` log, I found the error:

```
[   96.011927] bme680_i2c: Unknown symbol __devm_regmap_init_i2c (err -2)
```

`grep -nrwI __devm_regmap_init_i2c`, I saw this function declared in `include/linux/regmap.h` header file but there is no a definition for this function anywhere in source code.
In addition, I saw this function is exported with GPL license:

```
Module.symvers:10646:0x8037c97f __devm_regmap_init_i2c  drivers/base/regmap/regmap-i2c  EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
```

And the driver has `MODULE_LICENSE("GPL v2")` also.
Now, I don't know where this error comes from and how to resolve it, Can anyone help me? Thanks !!!

Comment: Had you run `depmod -a` on the target after copying new module(s)?

Comment: Thank you, I did, but same error still occurred.